# django ignore ordering parameter on model definition on query

Tags: django

On my model I have

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['title']
```

Is there a way I can leave this in the model definition as its useful elsewhere but in a query tell it to ignore it without having order by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation is your friend: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields

```
New in Django 1.0: Please, see the release notes

If you don't want any ordering to be applied to a query, 
not even the default ordering,  call order_by() with no parameters.
```